Обязателен ли тут знак препинания перед "Анненковым"?
Я был лично знаком с биографом Пушкина(?) Анненковым.

У Пушкина был не один биограф. Назван один.
Запятая - на авторское усмотрение.
Акцентируете, с каким именно из биографов, - ставите запятую, которая есть интонационное уточнение: "а именно".
Я был лично знаком с биографом Пушкина, Анненковым.
Просто называете фамилию биографа, с которым были лично знакомы, знак не нужен.
Я был лично знаком с биографом Пушкина Анненковым.
